# How to receive result of an intent on command line?

Tags: java, android, adb

Suppose I invoke an activity using adb
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n  -e key1 value1
Is there a way to receive its result(*) on shell prompt as well?
[I tried -W but that remains stuck foreve even after Activity is "finish"-ed]

- - At the minimum I am looking for return code of Activity, being able to see some parseable form of returned result intent would be even better.

Comment: Activities/Apps are not started like a regular command so I think there is no way to get a result from an app. You could write to logcat and parse that maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `System.exit(CODE);` to give back return code, yet it's not quite useful (unless you really got a reason for that).